# Filtering a Datatable with List c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to remove all Datatable rows containing existing sites provided in List. But the problem with my code is its only removing the last item of List from Datatable.

Sorry for a bit ambiguity in question for first time but fixing a legacy app so have to use .net 2.0 :( I knew the problem with my logic ,was just unable to find the alternate!

```
DataView cView = result.DefaultView;

foreach (string items in existingSites)
{
    cView.RowFilter = "Sites <> '" + items + "'";
}

dgvResult.DataSource = cView;
```

Comment: That's obvious right!

Comment: that's because the RowFilter is always going to be the last in your foreach loop. It doesn't accumulate the changes.

Comment: I knew what was wrong with my logic just asked for an alternative, but thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you keep resetting the filter. Try this:

```
DataView cView = result.DefaultView;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool first = true;

foreach (string items in existingSites)
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(" AND ");
    }

    sb.AppendFormat("Sites <> '{0}'", items);
}

cView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
dgvResult.DataSource = cView;
```

Of course, this is not the best solution if you can use newer framework options like LINQ (See Tim's answer).

Comment: Far less code to write doing it this way:
`var filter = string.Join(" AND ", existingSites.Select(a => string.Format("Sites <> '{0}'", a)));`

Comment: That includes LINQ. I tried not to use it since the ability of LINQ makes it even easier than this as pointed out by Tim.

Comment: sorry. didn't see that one. who is building new apps on .net < 3.5 anyway? ;)

Comment: sounds like it, at least :)

Comment: Nope, that's just an speculation. OP didn't mention the framework version. Moreover, this code has more number of lines but readability is much higher than a LINQ code. At least I liked it.

Comment: Thanks buddy :) But I am kind of surprised that how experienced programmers here are forgetting the fact that once they were learning as well.

Comment: @Has9: How do you mean your comment?

Answer (score 5):

Can you use LINQ (>= .NET 3.5) ?

```
DataTable result = result.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => !items.Contains(row.Field<string>("Sites")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: True but it looks like he still wants to keep his data as a DataView

Comment: @CathalMF: i don't understand why should he want that, however, he could simply use `dgvResult.DataSource = result.DefaultView;`.